# How to sanitize string for unix filename?

Tags: string, perl, escaping

In perl, how can I sanitise a string to be used as a filename in a Unix based system?

eg. AX/1234/BB would obviously need to have the forward slashes dealt with in some way.

Are there any modules that deal with this issue?

Answer (score 3):

A unix file name can contain any character except `/` and NUL, so the following makes sure `$fn` is a valid file name.

```
warn("Invalid file name") if $fn =~ m{[/\0]};
```

But you didn't say you wanted to detect bad file names; you said you wanted to sanitize them. However, you didn't say how. Perhaps you wish to replace the illegal characters with others? If so, you can use the following:

```
$fn =~ s{[/\0]}{_}g;
```

Comment: So why does `escape_filename` get rid of other characters as well as `/`?

Comment: @CJ7 There are a lot of characters which are legal in file names but extremely awkward if they are present, especially for command-line interfaces.  `escape_filename` addresses those too.

Comment: @CJ7 `mkdir chtest && cd chtest && perl -E 'mkdir $_ or warn "$! $_" for map { chr } (0..127)'` - will refuse the `.` (because current dir) and the `\0` and `/`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`File::Util` function `escape_filename`](http://search.cpan.org/~tommy/File-Util-3.27/Util.pod#escape_filename) does exactly this.

```
use File::Util;
$result = escape_filename($str);
```